# XML how to check if node is returning null?

Tags: c#, xml

i have this code in c#

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email").InnerText
```

how can i check whether it is returning null?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var n = doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email");
if (n != null) { // here is the check
  DoSomething(n.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By `null` do you mean that the element doesn't exist?

```
try
{
    var n = doc.SelectSingleNode("WhoisRecord/registrant/email");
    if (n == string.Empty) {
        // empty value
    }

    // has value
    DoSomething(n.InnerText);
}
catch (XPathException)
{
    // null value.
    throw;
}
```

I don't sure that it is correct, I need to test it.

Comment: Surprise! Assuming doc is an XmlDocument, there isn't one here :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
//assuming xd is a System.XML.XMLDocument...
XMLNode node = xd.SelectSingleNode("XPath");
if(node == null)
{
 //Your error handling goes here?
}else{
 // manipulate node.innerText 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Erm... with the `!=` operator - `!= null`? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.